# How to simplify c++ constructor that just copies the parameters to its fields?

Tags: c++, constructor, simplify

This is what I have:

```
class Vector3 {
    private:
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
    public:
        Vector3(float x = 0, float y = 0, float z = 0) {
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
            this->z = z;
        }
        ...
};
```

I find `this->something = something` very repetitive.
I just wanted to construct the Vector3 with the parameters once and

then never access the fields again, and just use methods to add the Vector3's.

Any way I can simplify the constructor to not have to do `this->something = something`?
Or any way to "seal" the fields?

Comment: You should prefer a member initializer list, for certain optimization reasons, but there's few good options for reducing verbosity

Comment: As a ratio of it's utility to how often it's taught in C++ courses, absolutely nothing beats the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor): `Vector3(float x = 0, float y = 0, float z = 0): x(x), y(y), z(z) {}`

Comment: In addition to using initialiser list, consider giving the arguments of the constructor a different name from members of the class.   Although it's acceptable for them to be the same (there are rules in the language to sort it out for constructor initialiser lists) a series of initialisers like `x(x), y(y), ...` is adding a cognitive load on the programmer which is not beneficial  [There are other contexts, such as a variable definition of the form `float x(x)`, in which a similar construct is syntactically valid but gives undefined behaviour].

Answer (score 5):

> Any way I can simplify the constructor to not have to do this->something = something?

You can use **member initializer list** to initialize the data members:

```
class Vector3 {
    private:
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
    public:
        Vector3(float x = 0, float y = 0, float z = 0): x(x), y(y), z(z) 
        {
        }
        ...
};
```

Comment: Yep this is the way to go. All the other answers are out of scope or way to complicated for a simple task

Comment: Thank you! This seems familiar to something I've seen before. God bless you all.

Answer (score 1):

Use an aggregate class. That's really the only alternative. It's not a *good* alternative, but it's the only alternative.

```
struct Vector3 {
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float z = 0;
};

class Vector3Thing {
    private:
        Vector3 vec;
    public:
        Vector3Thing(Vector3 vec_) : vec(vec_) {}
        ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::array` and `std::initializer_list`:

```
class Vector3
{
    enum elem
    {
        x,
        y,
        z,
        cnt
    };
    std::array<float, cnt> vec;
public:
    Vector3(const std::initializer_list<float>& list = {0.f,0.f,0.f})
    {
        std::copy(list.begin(), list.begin() + 3, vec.begin());
    }
    float get_x() { return vec[x]; }
    float set_x(float data) { vec[x] = data; }
};
```

It can be utilized like this.

```
Vector3 a = { 1.f,2.f,3.f };
Vector3 b{ 1.f,2.f,3.f };
```

Comment: The 3 lines of the constructor can be replaced with a single `std::copy`.

Comment: @273K I fixed it as per your advice. thx ^^7

Comment: Or could be shorter on 6 characters.